# Shapely & RTree vs. PostGIS/PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, shapely, rtree

I would really like some insight to the pros and cons of one approach versus the other.

I recently wrote some python code that inspects two layers of the same test ESRI GDB file using RTree (bounding box) and Shapely.  This was done on a thin client remotely accessing a Linux server running virtual instance of my Linux distro session (TRANSLATION:  Things run slow).

My code completed evaluating the test GDB (80MB) in ~ 84 seconds.  Very good given the environment I'm working in.

A co-worker of mine did the same evaluation **within the same environment** by first converting the test GDB file over to a postgreSQL database (~ 16 to 22 seconds) using OGR and then making the same evaluations in about 1 second.

My question to the community given the clear difference in performance is whether or not I should go all in with the PostgreSQL / PostGIS approach or are there cases where Shapely / R-Tree would be better?

Comment: Python and Shapely aren't intrinsically that much slower than PostGIS. And if you add the time required to install and configure PostGIS to the 23 seconds above, how would that compare to your script?There are lots of trade offs. Some of my coworkers love to use PostGIS as a data conversion workspace

Comment: @sgillies     I don't believe the installation and configuration of PostGIS matters in my case because it's always running in the background as I understand it.  The code my coworker uses simply converts the GDB into the postgresql database system already running.  So the 23 seconds really does account for that.  My initial concern was that if a GDB file was sufficiently large enough that the conversion process would be computationally prohibitive, but I've been told by another person that it's taken ~ 6 minutes to convert a 5GB GDB file.  That seems reasonable given the size.

Comment: Okay. I just wanted to point out one of the trade offs. I have colleagues who love to use PostGIS as an environment for transforming data. Myself, I seem to be always doing work that's not a fit for a database.

Comment: @sgillies      Yes.  I'm looking for any insights to tradeoffs I may be overlooking before I commit to using PostGIS/PostgreSQL for spatially analyzing data.  I was wondering that outside of the conversion matter if Shapely performed better in certain situations than using PostGIS/PostgreSQL.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 7):

It's possible PostGIS is doing something under the covers that you need to do by hand in Shapely. We use prepared geometry automatically in predicate loops, and in Shapely you might need to marshall that on purpose. Depends on what your process actually entails.

Advantages of python are the lower install overhead and the library of potential other features for your process you might install from pip. Advantage of postgis is multi-user view of the data and transaction integrity/performance under multi-user load.

Depending on your processing, the SQL approach to data filtering and processing will either be better-and-clearer or worse-and-confusing. Unfortunately it's not an unalloyed benefit.

If you also do ad hoc inspection of your data, you might find the database environment helpful, since little queries are just little queries, not whole new programs with loops etc (though using a REPL and being terse and pythonic, probably not much worse than doing SQL command-line inspection (see, I'm evolving)).

Comment: My co-worker's PostGIS / PostgreSQL approach is actually done via Python (including the conversion).  I was also curious to know if PostGIS is in fact doing something under the covers as the service is always on outside of code.  My co-worker is actually not using the PostGIS / PostgreSQL approach to exploit the advantages you speak of... he's just using built-in commands of PostGIS / PostgreSQL within Python to effectively find and point out the features of interest (i.e. buildings contained within perennial waters).  The nature of what I'm doing is ad hoc, but reused often.